# Spring Boot 3.0.0 Missing implementation of resolved method abstract void doFilterInternal

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm migrating application from Java 11 Spring Boot 2.7.0 to Java 17 Spring Boot 3.0.0 and getting error:

```
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 INFO  [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                             line: 173 : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 INFO  [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 525 : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 527 : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 551 : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 577 : Detected FixedThemeResolver 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 727 : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@6de84336 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 791 : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1d637673 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 542 : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.542 INFO  [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 547 : Completed initialization in 0 ms 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.589 ERROR [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]           line: 175 : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]

2022-12-15T10:06:21.623 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 119 : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={} 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.639 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping    line: 527 : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.701 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver      line: 354 : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.717 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-1 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line:1124 : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.839 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 119 : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={} 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.839 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping             line: 527 : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]] 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.854 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler          line: 557 : Resource not found 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.854 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line:1128 : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.870 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line: 119 : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={} 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.870 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping    line: 527 : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest) 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.901 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor       line: 275 : Using 'application/json', given [image/avif, image/webp, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json] 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.903 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor       line: 119 : Writing [{timestamp=Thu Dec 15 10:06:21 CET 2022, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/favicon.ico}] 
2022-12-15T10:06:21.923 DEBUG [http-nio-8200-exec-2 ] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                     line:1124 : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53855', transport: 'socket'
2022-12-15T10:07:41.497 INFO  [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.s.b.w.e.t.GracefulShutdown                  line:  53 : Commencing graceful shutdown. Waiting for active requests to complete 
2022-12-15T10:07:41.505 INFO  [tomcat-shutdown      ] o.s.b.w.e.t.GracefulShutdown                  line:  78 : Graceful shutdown complete 

Process finished with exit code 130
```

getting response from REST API

Answer (score 2):

One of custom libraries was incompatible with Java 17

It was a custom library, that used Java 11 "javax", not Java 17 "jakarta" packages. We rebuilt the library for Java 17. If you have similar problems look for javax packages in libraries that you are using