# Spring boot 3.0.2 Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.*) of abstract class filter.OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-migration-1.5.x-2.1.x

I'm migrating application from Java 11 Spring Boot 2.7.0 to Java 17 Spring Boot 3.0.0 , spring security 6.0.1 and getting error:

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
u2028   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
u2028   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
u2028   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
u2028   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
u2028   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
u2028   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
u2028   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)





[http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/ets/v1/service', GET], Filters=[]] (1/2)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.949+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5fa5d20d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4f7d5597, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5159969e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@543e126, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@36b62ef1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6a18bff6, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7e38440b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@53649db8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1882d510, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6c3f4afc, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@17a16484]] (2/2)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.949+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.957+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.957+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.957+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (3/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.context.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext - Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (5/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter - Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (6/11)
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SessionManagementFilter (9/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (10/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Invoking AuthorizationFilter (11/11)  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.965+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@5210f6c4]]  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.981+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] TRACE org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager - Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@5210f6c4]] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$1777/0x000000080195a478@123eb472  
2023-02-15 08:16:30.981+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error  
2023-02-15 08:16:31.037+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-1] DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request  
2023-02-15 08:16:31.680+0530 [] [http-nio-8484-exec-2] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
```

Above error I am getting while making api call

Updated my  java version to 17. and changed all imports to jakarta.* package.

Here is my security configuration :

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    

    http.csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
        .requestMatchers("/docs/*", "/WEB-INF/jsp/*", "/leap/**", "/leap/login.css", "/leap/css/**", "/leap/js/sign-up/**",
                "/leap/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/**", "/leap/assets/**", "/leap/js/**",
                "/leap/jquery/3.2.1/**", "/leap/font-google-open-sans-v14/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,  ControllerMappings.SERVICE, "/", "/WEB-INF/jsp/sign-up/.*(\\?.*)?", "/error").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .securityContext((securityContext) ->
        securityContext.requireExplicitSave(false)
    );

    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74811940/spring-boot-3-0-0-missing-implementation-of-resolved-method-abstract-void-dofilt