# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(..)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-migration

I am upgrading from spring boot 2.1.11_RELEASE to 3.0.6. But on hitting a particular api, I get this error on my **local** :

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.filter.RequestIdentifierFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestIdentifierFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [05/Jun/2023:16:06:35 +0530] 'GET /wallet-service/ve2/wallet/balance HTTP/1.1' 500 929 69440 '-' '-' '-'
```

and this error when I hit the api on **dev env**:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.xxx.xxx.api.util.AllowLoggedInUserFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void doFilterInternal(jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, jakarta.servlet.FilterChain)' of abstract class org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.
```

I have done the same upgradation with other services with similar code but has faced no errors including migrating from javax to jakarta.
This one is a particularly old service.
This question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74811940/spring-boot-3-0-0-missing-implementation-of-resolved-method-abstract-void-dofilt) doesn't solve my issue.

**UPDATE**
javax was being used in another class AllowLoggedInUserFilter from a common library which was being used in app configurations causing the issue. Since, I can't update AllowLoggedInUserFilter to jakarta right now I created my own replica of it using jakarta in service.

Comment: Sounds like: you just forgot to port com.xxx.api.util.AllowLoggedInUserFilter from `javax.servlet.*` to `jakarta.servlet.*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by xerx593, javax was being used in another class AllowLoggedInUserFilter from a common library which was being used in app configurations causing the issue. Since, I can't update AllowLoggedInUserFilter to jakarta right now I created my own replica of it using jakarta in service.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).